# Escaping single quote character breaks String.format(stringToFormat, formattingArguments)

Tags: apex, escape, string.format

When I run this code:

```
String.format('Dear {0}, Don\'t forget .... {1} .... {2}', args);
```

Token `0` is replaced, but token `1` and `2` appear as `{1}` and `{2}`

This is caused by the backslash escaping the single quote by the `t` character.

My work around it to do this:

```
String.format('Dear {0}, Don`t forget .... {1} .... {2}', args);
```

But I would like to know how I could escape the `'` character without breaking the merging of the arguments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String.format()` uses a Java [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) under the hood. One of the consequences of that is, well, this:

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes '' throughout a String. For example, pattern string "'{''}'" is interpreted as a sequence of '{ (start of quoting and a left curly brace), '' (a single quote), and }' (a right curly brace and end of quoting), not '{' and '}' (quoted left and right curly braces): representing string "{'}", not "{}".

Your single quote is treated as the start of a quoting region that prevents the formatter from interpreting the substitution variables `{1}` and `{2}`.

Basically, double all your single quotes in order to protect them from the formatting machinery. Since Apex, unlike Java, uses single quotes to delimit the string itself, you'll end up with `\'\'`. The backslash defends the single quote against the Apex parser, and the doubled single quote defends it against the Java formatter.

Further hilarity from the same Java documentation:

> The rules for using quotes within message format patterns unfortunately have shown to be somewhat confusing

Comment: Very very helpful its not confusing its super confusing : ). Thank you for the explanation !

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was really helpful!